# Rails searching query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a booking model in which i am rendering user who have created a booking. i want a search field where i can search with username and date range in which that specific user has created a booking.
can anyone help with that

```
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :property
  has_many :inquiries, dependent: :destroy
  
  enum status: [:Pending, :Approved]

class Property < ApplicationRecord
#  extend FriendlyId 

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :bookings,  dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :comapny
  has_many :reviews , dependent: :destroy

class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_many :properties
    has_many :bookings
    has_many :inquiries
    has_one :comapny
    has_many :reviews
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'd recommend against doing:

```rb
enum status: [:Pending, :Approved]
```

Instead you should probably go with the lower-case version, as per convention:

```rb
enum status: [:pending, :approved]
```

Then, if I've understood your question correctly, you want a search field that allows you to find bookings by the user's username and the date in which the booking was created, correct?

You'd need to provide a bit more code/context for me to answer this correctly (eg. what are the date fields called, what is the username field called?) but in general, I'd probably create a scope that looks like the following:

```rb
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  scope :by_username_and_booking_date, -> (start_date, end_date) {
    where('users.username = ?', user.username).where(booking_date: (start_date..end_date))
  }
end
```

And then you can call the search in your controller:

```rb
Booking.by_username_and_booking_date(start_date, end_date)
```